# Query nested, 2 leves, array of objects in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to query a coolection that has the following structure:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58eed22d09865610c23453e3"),
"name" : "Maria das Dores",
"type" : "P",
"nickname" : "Dolores",
"notes" : "Notas\r\n\r\nCom quebra de página",
"updated_at" : ISODate("2017-04-13T01:19:41.000Z"),
"created_at" : ISODate("2017-04-13T01:19:41.000Z"),
"emails" : [ 
    {
        "value" : "maria@dores.com",
        "default" : true,
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-04-13T01:19:41.000Z"),
        "created_at" : ISODate("2017-04-13T01:19:41.000Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("58eed22d09865610c23453e4")
    }, 
    {
        "value" : "maria@semdores.com",
        "_id" : ObjectId("58eed23d09865605614005c4"),
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-04-13T01:19:57.000Z"),
        "created_at" : ISODate("2017-04-13T01:19:57.000Z")
    }
],
"phones" : [ 
    {
        "value" : "(33) 8282383-2933",
        "default" : false,
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-04-25T12:11:14.000Z"),
        "created_at" : ISODate("2017-04-13T01:19:41.000Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("58eed22d09865610c23453e5")
    }, 
    {
        "value" : "(85) 101010-1010101",
        "default" : true,
        "_id" : ObjectId("58ff3ce209865605681f40c2"),
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-04-25T12:11:14.000Z"),
        "created_at" : ISODate("2017-04-25T12:11:14.000Z")
    }, 
    {
        "value" : "21343243343",
        "_id" : ObjectId("58ff3d7d0986560b861c3b32"),
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-04-25T12:13:49.000Z"),
        "created_at" : ISODate("2017-04-25T12:13:49.000Z")
    }
],
"copartner" : {
    "enabled" : true,
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-05-17T00:32:42.000Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-05-11T02:35:40.000Z"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("5913cdfc09865664df031ec2"),
    "applications" : {
        "0" : {
            "application_id" : "58e46443098656283d225b52",
            "responsibility" : "DEV",
            "percentage" : 1250,
            "_id" : ObjectId("591a6f9d0986563c174cefd3"),
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-05-16T03:18:53.000Z"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-05-16T03:18:53.000Z")
        },
        "1" : {
            "application_id" : "58e46443098656283d225b52",
            "responsibility" : "SALE",
            "percentage" : 2000,
            "_id" : ObjectId("591b9a2a09865605697fe3e3"),
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-05-17T00:32:42.000Z"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-05-17T00:32:42.000Z")
        }
    }
}
}
```

I already test with the "dot" notation and using `$elemMatch`, but no one of them result in any match.

Dot notation query:

```
db.getCollection('persons').find({
    "copartner.applications.application_id": "58e46443098656283d225b52"
})
```

$elemMatch query:

```
db.getCollection('persons').find({
    "copartner.applications": { $elemMatch: { "applications_id": "58e46443098656283d225b52" } }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot notation will work with either one of these queries:

```
db.getCollection('persons').find({
"copartner.applications.0.application_id": "58e46443098656283d225b52"})
```

AND

```
db.getCollection('persons').find({
"copartner.applications.1.application_id": "58e46443098656283d225b52"})
```

"applications" is not an array, so $elemMatch is not applicable.  "0" and "1" are nested fields instead of array elements.  If you can, you're better off using an array for "applications".

Comment: Oh God, I really didn't see my mistake, I'm saving as an object instead of as an array, thanks a lot